# how to create new file using python

Tags: python, macos, osx-leopard

how can i create new file in /var/log directory using python language in OSX leopard? i tried to do it using os.open function but i get "permission denied"

thanks in advance

Comment: Not really a programming question.  Permission issues are part of superuser.com.

Comment: its tagged as python that means "os.open" is  a python function.

Answer (score 6):

Only root can write in `/var/log/` on Mac OS X...:

```
$ ls -ld /var/log
drwxr-xr-x  60 root  wheel  2040 Oct  6 17:00 /var/log
```

Maybe consider using the `syslog` module in the standard library...

Comment: @nur, `import syslog` of course -- see http://docs.python.org/library/syslog.html for all the details!

Comment: @alex thank u very much. actually what i want to achieve is that, i am writing a launchagent application for osx using python. it writes some meta info in a sqlite db from time to time. these data cannot be seen by user without root privilege. so i need to keep this db file in place where only root has access. how can i achieve that?

Comment: @nur, you can achieve that only by running as root (not recommended, but it IS the only way to do exactly what you ask: update a sqlite db which ONLY root can access).

Answer (score 1):

It probably failed because /var/log has user set to root and group set to wheel. Try running your python code as root and it will probably work.

Comment: thank u. my application is a launchagent application. it runs during start up and saves some data in file time to time. data saved by the application cannot be viewed without root privilege. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the log file as root and then change the owner to the user your script is run as

```
# touch /var/log/mylogfile
# chown myuser /var/log/mylogfile
```

where mylogfile is your logfile and myuser is the user the script will be run as

also look into logrotate